# Load data to a listview control from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to retrieve data from SQL Server into my form. I am trying with the below code. When I  run this I get the first item or row but I am unable load the rest of the items into my listview . Can someone help to solve my issue?

```
Sub GetInvoiceDetails()
    Dim Inv As New petClass
    Dim dt As DataTable = Inv.GetInvoiceDetailsbyNo(txtInvoiceNo.Text)
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For Each row In dt.Rows
            srno += 1
            Dim lstitem = Lstview.Items.Add(srno)
            lstitem.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows(0).Item("ItemName").ToString)
            lstitem.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows(0).Item("SellingPrice".ToString)).ToString()
        Next
    End If
    'clearcontrols
End Sub
```

Comment: Dont you need to increment the rows, in addition `dt.rows(i)` where i is an index?

Comment: What is `srno` ?  This is very bad code sorry.

Comment: Why can't you assign the DataTable to the "DataSource" attribute of the ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're always using the first row in the DataTable with `dt.Rows(0)`.

Instead:

```
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    srno += 1
    Dim lstitem = Lstview.Items.Add(srno)
    lstitem.SubItems.Add(row.Field(of String)("ItemName"))
    lstitem.SubItems.Add(row.Field(Of String)("SellingPrice"))
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing i see is that you're referencing only the first row of your datatable. 
Try this:

```
Sub GetInvoiceDetails()
    Dim Inv As New petClass
    Dim dt As DataTable = Inv.GetInvoiceDetailsbyNo(txtInvoiceNo.Text)
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For Each row In dt.Rows
            srno += 1
            Dim lstitem = Lstview.Items.Add(srno)
            lstitem.SubItems.Add(row.Items("ItemName").ToString)
            lstitem.SubItems.Add(row.Items("SellingPrice".ToString)).ToString()
        Next
    End If
    'clearcontrols
End Sub
```

Next thing, I'm a bit confused by what you're trying to do here:

```
            lstitem.SubItems.Add(row.Items("SellingPrice".ToString)).ToString()
```

You shouldn't need the second ToString(), no??

Comment: I am getting this error when i use your mention code "Public member 'Items' on type 'DataRow' not found "